# Sometimes Font Awesome only shows rectangle and numbers

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'am using Font Awesone like this:

```
<link href=".../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg myownclass">
```

It works in IE, Chrome and Firefox - und sometimes in Opera. Now my customer told me, that he also not see the Icon on Firefox/Windows.

Do you have an idea what's the problem? Opera sometimes shows me the Icons, sometimes only rectangles or numbers.

Can you help me? Could it be a problem of caching?

Comment: i get error this. On chorme, i click inspect and i get error. It is mean i without folder webfonts you need coppy webfonts [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyt8f.png)
download here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself all.css is awesome css this is solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmht7.png)

Answer (score 4):

All Font-Awesome icons need to be given the `fa` class in order to properly assign the Font-Awesome font:

```
<span class="fa fa-stack fa-lg myownclass">
             ^^
```

Unless this is being defined in your `.myownclass` class, the Font-Awesome font will not be active.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add following on your html, head'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/v4-shims.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: checkout @James Donnely's answer: you definitely should add the `fa` class.

When you only see rectangles etc. it means that the browser didn't load the font file (considering *sometimes* you do actually see the fa-icons), and it's showing unknown character files (unicode characters like `\f16c`) as squares or something else, designating it doesn't know what the heck to do with those characters.

So whenever this happens open up a developer tools screen and check if you see any errors. Furthermore, be sure the font file is loaded from a stable server. Also, if you load the font-file from a relative path, it could be the case that on certain pages (eg. `/blog/an-article`) it can't find the file, while on others (`/blog`) the relative path is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. 
I changed the code to:

```
<span class="fa fa-stack fa-lg myclass">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x">
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">
</span>
```

But there ar no changes, I cant understand. Perhaps it is realy only a problem of loading local the data. I give up for now.